# Facebook Page not Displaying Google Map Frame in Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-maps, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, mozilla

to all. I am new to Google Map APi.

I have made the Dynamic Google Map which fetches the values from My DB.

Here, is it http://pollinator.org/fb/sharapp/

and I have added that page using my app on FB on this link :

https://www.facebook.com/ThePollinatorPartnership/app_512541485429310

I can show exactly output in All browsers except Mozilla Firefox 24 and Google Chrome Browser.

I have also HTTPS connection link for that,

I tried also above link to integrate into the my FB page. But, Its also not showing in Mozilla and Chrome.

If anyone have solution please help me to solve out. I have tried lot of solutions.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do you have any error on your console?

Comment: Of course he does … “blocked mixed content”, because Googl Maps API was embedded per HTTP when Facebook is surfed via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

instead of

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

Google Chrome and Firefox will block a unsecure url due to browser security settings